# What does this red minus overlay icon mean in Visual studio's Solution Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

[image]

What does this red minus flag mean in visual studio?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I believe this means the file is excluded from the build.

Note that this seems to be a bit different from "Exclude from project", in that the file shows up in the listing, but if you right-click on it and look at Properties > General, Exclude from build is set to Yes.
If you set it to No, the red minus goes away.

One more datapoint, the project I imported started out as a VC6 project so this might be Visual Studio 2010's way of representing a legacy setting that was different than Exclude from Project.

The other comment about it indicating a missing item shows an exclamation point icon, not a minus.

Answer (score 2):

Red circle icon with white minus means that file is excluded from source code control.
Right click on filter "Header files" for example and find out how "SCC Files" property is set. Probably is set to false,  change it to true and icon will disappear.

Comment: This answer ir wrong. I'm not using source control in VS and the icon appears. @Shimona Carvalho's answer is the right one.