# VS 2015 Solution Explorer File Icons

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, solution-explorer, file-icons

In Visual Studio 2015 Solution Explorer next to C++ files is a "++" icon, easy enough to understand, but I have one C++ file that has a red circle with a white minus sign in it over the "++" icon.  I have tried making changes to this file and checking it into TFS, the icon does not change.

Short questions: What does a red circle with a white minus sign in it over the "++" icon mean??
[image: we]

Bonus question: I searched all over trying to get a list of the icons, without any success, does a list of these icons exist??

07.Nov.2016 Update:  This question was asked and answered in 2012, but I feel this posting should remain, because both the question and answer include screen shots.  A picture is worth a least a 1,000 words!

Comment: I think it means that the file is not under source control, old link but still relevant: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181372(v=vs.80).aspx other icons: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: I already had seen that definition, it is for a white circle with a red minus sign.  The question is for a red circle with a white minus sign, and this file is in the TFS, I have checked it out, made changes and checked it back in, and the icon does not change.

Comment: a very simple question.... after 24 hours and 17 people viewing it, there is still no simple answer??   :(

Comment: After 6 days, only 20 views and no answers???  So I am starting to think there is not an answer, that these icons are no where documented??

Comment: You may get more joy on the Microsoft forum, sorry I couldn't help but I can't reproduce this icon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this red minus overlay icon mean in Visual studio's Solution Explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259323/what-does-this-red-minus-overlay-icon-mean-in-visual-studios-solution-explorer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the file is excluded from the build. Right click on a file - `Properties` - `Configuration Properties` - `General` and see if the `Excluded From Build` is set to **Yes**. Setting it to **No** removes the icon.
[image: Exclude from build]

Comment: YES!  Thank-You!  At first it did not seem to make a difference, then I set the Configuration to "All Configurations" and set the "Excluded From Builld" to "NO", and the icon is gone!