# How to fix the red minus flag on my vb.net project on vs2017

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, vb.net-2010

I need to fix the red flag marks on my vb.net projects. See here:

[image: Screenshot]

I believe it's one of the projects that isn't included in the build. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259323/what-does-this-red-minus-overlay-icon-mean-in-visual-studios-solution-explorer) earlier but I can't find the general tab she was talking about. I also tried navigating the solution explorer but can't seem to find the right answer for this.

Comment: We need more information than this - please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Im sorry for my bad format of question, im just trying to find some answers. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mouse over the icon, a tooltip should appear indicating the meaning of the icon. According to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181372%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), this icon "represents an item that is not under Team Foundation version control".