# Visual studio 2019 or GIT is ignoring newly added files in the solution even the file extension is not mention in .gitignore

Tags: git, visual-studio

[image]

If you see the image two .cs files are locked and i just added Test.cs file in project and it is started showing as ignored file.
Is there any way to make all newly added files automatically added to source control?.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the file in question > Under the Exclude From Project, select the option "Add ignored file to Source Control"

Answer (score 3):

The "red minus overlay icon in Visual studio's Solution Explorer?" should means "[excluded from build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14491702/6309)", not "ignored by Git".

Double-check in command-line with:

```
cd /path/to/project
git check-ignore -v -- Test.cs
```

If it is *also* ignored, that check-ignore command will give you the exact `.gitignore` and rule.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the file  Select **Git** => **Add Ignored file to source control**

[image]